# How to convert an index.html route directed to an angular 8 app into angular route that contains the original parameters?

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

[Current test routing setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qovKO.png)The vendor we use sends users to our site with a url like this: 'http://images.rsna.org/index.html?doi=10.1148/rg.2018170120&fig=fig1a'. The only thing that changes is the doi parameter and the fig parameter. I am converting the site to an angular 8 application, but I still need to be able to accept this as a route. Is there a way to accept this as a route, then redirect to either the '/browse' or '/viewer' routes that exist on the site while maintaining the doi and fig parameters in case of a page reload? I need the parameters on a reload to be able to grab the data from the database or to make the api call to grab updated data with those values.

Comment: could you please provide your Angular routing configuration?

Comment: @Andrei That's what I'm trying to find out how to do for this scenario. My current setup is only for testing purposes. I currently hard coded the api call on load of the browse or viewer route, and I switch between those two routes, but the live product will load on a link like the one I posted in the description.

Comment: I currently just have two routes: '/browse' and '/viewer' that resolve after getting the data from the hard coded api call. I would want to convert those to having the doi and fig parameters included.

Comment: where is the "redirect" happends? BE of FE?

Comment: @Andrei I have an empty route that redirects to '/browse', but again, I don't know how to make the route to handle the link I posted. Would it be path: 'index.html?doi=:doi&fig=:fig' or how would I build that?

Answer (score 0):

Using canActivate guard was the way to do this. I needed to pair this with a resolver to use the ActivatedRouteSnapshot and be able to extract the parameters to be passed around.